# PWA: hide address bar when opening external url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I would like to hide the default address bar when opening up an external link from inside my PWA.
The external url is opened using `window.open('https://externalsite.com/', '_self')`.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn03q.jpg) is how the address bar looks when accessing via android (default chrome gets opened).

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I believe that is a security feature to let users know that they may be entering in information on another site than the PWA they are using. There to help your users.

Comment: Hi @Mathias, thank you for the quick response. Is there a way to disable this?
I knew a PWA created using wordpress that can open another external site (different domain) but hide the address bar, making the user experience more seamless.

Edit: It is WP site using plugin named Super Progressive Web Apps.

Comment: I don't THINK so since it is there as a security feature to prevent people from developing something malicious. Letting people know when they have left the original website they are using and possibly entering in secure information on another site.. But perhaps someone else knows how it can be done and will provide a solution.

Comment: To do this, through your proxy, that is, everything on your domain, will not go out. Or open link in a iframe =)

Comment: some websites block iframe with the appropriate http header. not a good solution